# Do I need to care OOB approval workflow's (global reusable workflow) publisher?

Tags: workflow, deployment

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. On one of site collection, I login as test.com\admin and created a workflow using OOB Approval Workflow. It works fine on the test environment.

We are going to deploy the site to production environment using Restore-SPSite method. However, test.com\admin is not exist on production environment (the production environment is on prod.com domain). Do I need to reactivate (or re-create, or re-publish using SPD2013) the workflow using a production account (hence, prod.com\admin)?

Answer (score 1):

The restored workflow can be started by any user having the *Edit Items* permission on the list where the workflow is. To edit the workflow, users with *Manage Lists* permission can change the workflow. It doesn’t matter who created the workflow, it will still be in place and functioning even if your user doesn’t exist in the production environment.

> **To add a workflow** By default, you must have the *Manage Lists* permission to add a workflow. (The Owners group has the Manage Lists permission by default; the Members group and the Visitors group do not.)
>
> **To start a workflow** Also by default, you must have the *Edit Items* permission to start a workflow that’s already been added. (The Members group and the Owners group both have the Edit Items permission by default; the Visitors group does not.)

Reference: [Overview of workflows included with SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Overview-of-workflows-included-with-SharePoint-d74fcceb-3a64-40fb-9904-cc33ca49da56)

Comment: Although you have clearly answered my question, may I know your reference article have talked about it? Thanks.

Comment: @Mark Not specifically, but it explains workflow permissions. And once the workflow is created, it's a component of the list regardless of who created it. You could test it by backing up a site (with a workflow on a list) in one environment and restore it to a different farm where the user created a workflow doesn't have access.

Comment: Benny, I deploy the site collection (with workflow) to another farm using Restore-SPSite method. Whenever start the workflow it went fail. Error is "The workflow operation failed because the workflow lookup found no matching item". I think the GUIDs will remain the same. Not sure why the error.

Comment: After I republish the workflow with a user exist on new farm. It works again. Thanks.